# Lift chart randomly chosen case

Tags: classification

"For example, consider a list of 100 customers, half of whom churn (positive instances) and half who do not (negative instances). If you scan down the list and stop halfway (representing 0.5 targeted), how many positives would you expect to have seen in the first half? If the list were sorted randomly, you would expect to have seen only half the positives (0.5), giving a lift of 0.5/ 0.5 = 1."

How we can be sure that we should see half the possitives if sortes randomly ?

Comment: "Expect to" does not mean being "sure."

Comment: thank you. Why we expect to see half ? Is it a norm in Stat ?

Comment: If you randomly sample half of a population, you expect to see half of any subpopulation.